# How one can use Python script in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: ubuntu, python, libreoffice

Can one use Python scripts in Libreoffice macros? I have Libreoffice calc 6.0.7.3 and Ubuntu 18.04. I installed `libreoffice-script-provider-python`. But how can I make some basic computation that tests if everything works? For example, if cell A1 contains value 1 and A2 contains value 2, then how can I compute (A1+A2)**4 via Python and put the value to the cell A3?

Comment: The tutorial [Interface-oriented programming in OpenOffice / LibreOffice : automate your office tasks with Python Macros](https://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) looks promising. Unfortunately, I use Java for Libreoffice automation and only know a wee bit of Python, so I can't really offer any help with specifics.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://superuser.com/questions/1519259/how-can-i-use-python-macros-in-libreoffice-calc.